# Random number generation using Java 8

Tags: java, security, random

I'm working on Java 8 code to generate one time passwords (random).
Below are the security requirements:

Following are the approved PRNG mechanisms:
· HASH_DRBG
· HMAC_DRBG
· CTR_DRBG#

I know that Java 9 SecureRandom supports these mechanisms, but how about Java 8?
Anyway to achieve this using Java 8 code?

Thanks a lot,
Raj

Comment: You can always look at the Java 9 reference implementation and copy it...

Comment: You can type any of these algorithms into Google together with the keyword "java" and browse through the results. I see some lesser known open source implementations, and I see the Bouncycastle crypto provider. You need to do some research before asking a question on SO  so that you can ask a good, specific question.

Comment: The [openjdk reference implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk12u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/security/SecureRandom.java) seems to rely on sun.security.*. It is recommended to [not use sun.*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) packages. So yes the suggestion to find a third-party provider is likely to be better.